# python- reverse 2 strings in 1 list separately?

Tags: python

In python, I have this list containing

```
['HELLO', 'WORLD']
```

how do I turn that list into

```
['OLLEH', 'DLROW']
```

Answer (score 9):

```
>>> words = ['HELLO', 'WORLD']
>>> [word[::-1] for word in words]
['OLLEH', 'DLROW']
```

Comment: @user2278906 You should check the mark next to his answer if you feel it helped you best.

Answer (score 3):

Using a list comprehension:

```
reversed_list = [x[::-1] for x in old_list]
```

Answer (score 1):

Arguably using the builtin `reversed` is more clear than slice notation `x[::-1]`.

```
[reversed(word) for word in words]
```

or

```
map(reversed, words)
```

Map is fast without the lambda.

I just wish it was easier to get the string out of the resulting iterator. Is there anything better than `''.join()` to put together the string from the iterator?

Comment: This isn't a full answer and no, there is nothing easier than having to use `''.join` to put it together

Comment: `[''.join(reversed(word)) for word in words]` is the full version of your first solution, which is valid and some argue it is more readable than `[::-1]`, but I am of the opinion that the reverse slice is much better

Answer (score 0):

Using `map` and `lambda`(lambdas are slow):

```
>>> lis=['HELLO', 'WORLD']
>>> map(lambda x:x[::-1],lis)
['OLLEH', 'DLROW']
```

Comment: why the downvote? Is the answer not useful or incorrect anyhow?

Comment: map/lambda combo is [unpythonic](http://www.python.org/doc/essays/ppt/regrets/PythonRegrets.pdf), and should not be recommended where a list comprehension is the one obvious way